# How to prevent FlowPane from wrapping (vertically) when end of Scene is reached

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
    flowPane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

    for(int i = 0; i < 101;i++) {
        Label aLabel = new Label("Label number: " + i);
        flowPane.getChildren().add(aLabel);
    }

    Scene applicationScene = new Scene(flowPane);
    stage.setHeight(400.0);
    stage.setWidth(400.0);
    stage.setScene(applicationScene);
    stage.show();
}
```

I am trying to write the code so that all of the labels end up in the same column even though the labels will not be within the window (I plan on adding a scrollPane to make the labels still viewable issue). However, I have no clue as to why, since the labels automatically begin filling up the next column when the first one is filled ([example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If2TG.png)). How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no clue as to why since the labels automatically begin filling
>   up the next column when the first one is filled

That's the functionality of a `FlowPane`. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html):

> FlowPane lays out its children in a flow that wraps at the flowpane's
>   boundary. ... A vertical flowpane lays out nodes in columns, wrapping at the flowpane's height.

You should use a [`VBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html) instead:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    VBox vbox = new VBox();

    for(int i = 0; i < 101;i++) {
        Label aLabel = new Label("Label number: " + i);
        vbox.getChildren().add(aLabel);
    }

    Scene applicationScene = new Scene(vbox);
    stage.setHeight(400.0);
    stage.setWidth(400.0);
    stage.setScene(applicationScene);
    stage.show();
}
```

If you have a lot of data to display, you might also consider using a [`ListView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html). The `ListView` has a more complex API (it manages selection, and can be editable if you choose), and provides its own scrollbars when needed, but it can be more efficient for large amounts of data (basically it only creates UI controls for the visible data, and reuses them as the user scrolls).